# Text cut off with special characters

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, collation

WordPress or PHP are cutting off the text after saving a post. This happens when there is a special character like ’ or ™. 
For example if I enter the following text:

```
This isn’t working
```

and then I save the post, the post will be:

```
This isn
```

I assume is not MySQL because I entered the same text and it worked.
The wp-config.php contains the following:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

And I have tested it with

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'latin1_swedish_ci');
```

The mysql database has latin1_swedish_ci collation and the tables has utf8_general_ci collation.

I've also tried to change the tables collation but it didn't work. I'm using the latest WordPress version. I don't have experience with collations or encoding. So, my question is: Is there a method to make WordPress save the entirely post without cutting off the content when appears a special character?

Answer (score 0):

The truncation like that very probably came from latin1 *bytes* being fed to a utf8 field.

*If* your client (PHP or whatever) is generating latin1 characters, then you *must* tell the server that:

```
⚈  mysql: mysql_set_charset('utf8');  (deprecated)
⚈  mysqli: $mysqli_obj->set_charset('utf8');
⚈  PDO: $db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pwd);
```